# Spring profiles not getting resolved when using it with the spring web based project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

in application.properties given : spring.profiles.active=DEV 
and in dev config file : mentioned all the mongo connection properties

and added the configuration java file like

```
@Configuration

@PropertySource("classpath:userIdentity_Dev.properties")

@Profile("DEV")
public class UserIdentityConfigDev
{

}
```

when running the application the spring profiler is not getting resolved the

below stack trace is received

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userIdentityService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userIdentityBusiness'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userIdentityBusiness': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userIdentityRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userIdentityRepositoryImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mongodb.userIdentity.host' in string value "${mongodb.userIdentity.host}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
```

Saying that the ${mongodb.userIdentity.host} property is not resolved

when creating war and jar file for the project the spring profile is not resolved

Comment: Can you post your properties file and class that use it?

Answer (score 0):

This is main class:

` @SpringBootApplication(exclude= {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class ,MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})

@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")

public class ApplicationStart  extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{

public static void main(String[] args)

```
{

    SpringApplication.run(ApplicationStart.class,args);

}
```

}`

below is the property file:

```
## MongoDB Connection Properties-----------------
```

### MongoDB database

mongodb.userIdentity.database = UserIdentity_CS

### isConnectionStringUsed is true then application creates connection as per connectionString else it will use MongoDB single server properties.

mongodb.userIdentity.isConnectionStringUsed = false

### connectionString with authentication

## mongodb.connectionString = mongodb://sa:Test%40123@SPT-CPU-0259:27017,SPT-CPU-0173:27017/admin?replicaSet=surveillens

### connectionString without authentication

mongodb.userIdentity.connectionString = mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=surveillens

### MongoDB single server properties.

mongodb.userIdentity.host = localhost

mongodb.userIdentity.port = 27017

### Authentication properties

mongodb.userIdentity.isAuthenticationEnable = false

mongodb.userIdentity.userName = sa

mongodb.userIdentity.password = Test@123

mongodb.userIdentity.authDB = admin

## Collection Name for user Identity

mongodb.userIdentity.collectionName = CreditScore

### Other properties -----------------------

userIdentity.ValidKeySet = email;phonenumber;_id

userIdentity.logsFolder = ./IdentityLogs/

userIdentity.insertBatchSize = 100

and below is the file .java file where all this properties are used
`
@Configuration
public abstract class MongoDbRepository  {

```
private Class<T> clazz;
private static MongoClient mongoClient = null;
private static MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = null;
private static ObjectMapper mapper = null;

@Value("${mongodb.userIdentity.host}")
private  String mongoHost;

@Value("${mongodb.userIdentity.port}")
private int mongoPortNumber;

@Value("${mongodb.userIdentity.database}")
private String mongoDatabaseName;

@Value("${mongodb.userIdentity.userName}")
private String mongoUserName;

@Value("${mongodb.userIdentity.authDB}")
private String mongoAuthDB;

@Value("${mongodb.userIdentity.password}")
private String mongoPassword;

@Value("${mongodb.userIdentity.isAuthenticationEnable}")
private boolean mongoIsAuthEnable;

@Value("${mongodb.userIdentity.isConnectionStringUsed}")
private boolean mongoIsConnectionStringUsed;

@Value("${mongodb.userIdentity.connectionString}")
private String mongoConnectionString;

public final void setClazz(Class<T> clazzToSet)
{
    this.clazz = clazzToSet;
}

/**
 * Instantiates a new mongo base repository.
 * @throws Exception
 */
public MongoDbRepository()
{
    //Trigger MongoDB Connection initialization

    if(mongoClient == null)
    {
        prepareMongoConnection();
    }
    else
    {
        // Trigger any method to check MongoDB client is connected
        mongoClient.getAddress();
    }

    // Trigger ObjectMapper initialization
    if(mapper == null)
        prepareObjectMapper();
}

/**
 * Instantiates a new mongoDB connection.
 * @throws Exception
 */
private void prepareMongoConnection()
{
    if (mongoConnectionString != null && !mongoConnectionString.isEmpty())
    {
        boolean isConnectionStringUsed = mongoIsConnectionStringUsed;

        if(isConnectionStringUsed)
        {
            MongoClientURI clientUri = new MongoClientURI(mongoConnectionString);
            mongoClient = new MongoClient(clientUri);
        }
        else
        {
            if(mongoIsAuthEnable)
            {
                MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoUserName, mongoAuthDB, mongoPassword.toCharArray());
                mongoClient = new MongoClient( new ServerAddress(mongoHost, mongoPortNumber), Arrays.asList(credential));
            }
            else
                mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoHost, mongoPortNumber);
        }

        // Trigger any method to check MongoDB client is connected
        mongoClient.getAddress();
        // Get Database from mongoClient.
        mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase(mongoDatabaseName);
    }
}

/**
 * Get an objectMapper.
 */
private void prepareObjectMapper()
{
    mapper = CommonFunctions.getObjectMapper();
}

/**
 * Get the MongoDB collection object from MongoDB.
 *
 * @param collectionName is Name of a MongoDB collection
 * @return Collection object
 * @throws Exception
 */
private MongoCollection<Document> getCollection(String collectionName) throws Exception
{
    if(mongoClient == null)
        prepareMongoConnection();
    return mongoDatabase.getCollection(collectionName);
}

/*   ------- Find functions -------   */

/**
 * Find one documents from mongoDB collection.
 *
 * @param collectionName the collection name
 * @param query the query document - set to empty document means no query filtering.
 *
 * @return entityObj the entity Object
 * @throws Exception the exception
 */
public T findOne(String collectionName, Object query) throws Exception
{
    if(clazz == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("ST224 - Generic class is null - set the generic class before perform MongoDB operation");

    MongoCollection<Document> collection = getCollection(collectionName);
    Document mongoDoc = collection.find(convertToBsonDocument(query)).first();

    String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(mongoDoc);
    T entityObj =  mapper.readValue(jsonStr, clazz);

    return entityObj;
}
```

}`